# Creating an array from file and name it based on a line in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have text file like this:

```
src_dir=source1
src_dir=source2
dst_dir=dest1
whatever_thing=thing1
whatever_thing=thing2
```

I want a script that will create arrays with names from the left part of a line and fill it with elements from the right part of a line. So basically it should do:

```
src_dir=(source1 source2)
dst_dir=(dest1)
whatever_thing=(thing1 thing2)
```

I've tried so far:

```
while read -r -a line
do
    IFS='= ' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
    "${array[0]}"+="${array[1]}"
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `bash` version is 4.3 or newer, `declare` has an `-n` option
to define a rerefence to the variable name which works as a `reference` in `C++`.
Then please try the following:

```
while IFS== read -r key val; do
    declare -n name=$key
    name+=("$val")
done < file.txt

# test
echo "${src_dir[@]}"
echo "${dst_dir[@]}"
echo "${whatever_thing[@]}"
```

Comment: @Inian Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also I wouldn't call name references as pointers, they are more analogous to references in C++

Comment: @Inian I agree. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t arr < YourDataFile.txt
declare -A dict
for line in "${arr[@]}"; do
    key="${line%%=*}"
    value="${line#*=}"
    [ ${dict["$key"]+X} ] && dict["$key"]+=" $value" || dict["$key"]="$value"
done

for key in "${!dict[@]}"; do
    printf "%s=(%s)\n" "$key" "${dict["$key"]}"
done
```

**explanation**

```
# read file into array
mapfile -t arr < YourDataFile.txt

# declare associative array
declare -A dict

# loop over the data array
for line in "${arr[@]}"; do

    # extract key
    key="${line%%=*}"

    # extract value
    value="${line#*=}"

    # write into associative array
    #   - if key exists ==> append value
    #   - else initialize entry
    [ ${dict["$key"]+X} ] && dict["$key"]+=" $value" || dict["$key"]="$value"
done

# loop over associative array
for key in "${!dict[@]}"; do

    # print key=value pairs
    printf "%s=(%s)\n" "$key" "${dict["$key"]}"
done
```

**output**

```
dst_dir=(dest1)
src_dir=(source1 source2)
whatever_thing=(thing1 thing2)
```